# A simple question about sqllite, stuck in the learning process

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm trying to learn myself some sqlite. And i'm making some exercises.
I' m practicing in the sqlite practice area from W3 schools.
**The question is to make the following query: Get the most expensive order(note. Some orders consist of more then one product(id))**
I'm stuck in how I query for the sum of al the products related to the orderId.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

```
SELECT o.orderId,SUM(quantity*price) as totaal FROM [Orders] AS o
LEFT JOIN orderdetails AS ord ON O.orderId = ord.orderid
LEFT JOIN products AS P ON P.productid = ord.productId
GROUP BY O.orderId
ORDER BY Totaal DESC
LIMIT 1
```